# RESTful controller inside other URI controller in ASP.NET Web API (Nested controllers)

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm new at writing RESTful web services and I want to build a RESTful web service using ASP.NET Web API that third-party developers will use to access my application's data.

My controller was designed to respond to the following URIs:

```
api/warehouse --> return list of warehouses
api/warehouse/001 --> return warehouse 001
api/Binwarehouse --> return list of bins by  warehouses
api/Binwarehouse/001 --> return list of bins for warehouse 001
```

but what i really need to do is make this uri structure works

```
api/warehouse/001/Binwarehouse --> return a list of  bins for warehouse 001
api/warehouse/001/Binwarehouse/020 --> return bin "020" from warehouse 001

instead
api/Binwarehouse --> return list of bins by  warehouses
api/Binwarehouse/001 --> return list of bins for warehouse 001
```

How can I do that if this is my code?

GLOBAL.ASAX

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace PSWMWrapperApi
{
    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterOpenAuth();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "ApiClientes", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{dni}",
                defaults: new { dni = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional });
        }     
    }
}
```

WarehouseController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace PSWMWrapperApi
{
    public class WarehouseController : ApiController
    {          
        private Warehouse[] MostrarLista()
        {
            DataSet dsTemp = Funciones.ListaAlmacenes(Funciones.String_ConectaStatic, "1", "1", "1");    
            Warehouse[] listaBodegas = null;

            if (dsTemp != null)
            {
                DataTable oDtTemp = dsTemp.Tables[0];
                if (oDtTemp != null)
                {
                    listaBodegas = new Warehouse[oDtTemp.Rows.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < oDtTemp.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow orow =   oDtTemp.Rows[i];
                        listaBodegas[i] = new Warehouse(orow["WarehouseId"].ToString(), orow["WarehouseDscr"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            return listaBodegas;
        }

        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<Warehouse> Get()
        {
            return MostrarLista();
           // return listaClientes;
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/44444444K
        public Warehouse Get(String dni)
        {
           return MostrarLista().Where(x => x.WarehouseId == dni).FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
}
```

BinWarehouseController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Data;

namespace PSWMWrapperApi
{
    public class BinWarehouseController : ApiController
    {
        private BinWarehouse[] MostrarLista()
        {

            DataSet dsTemp = Funciones.ListaBinsAlmacenes(Funciones.String_ConectaStatic, "1", "1","","");    // _fun.ListaAlmacenes( );
            BinWarehouse[] listaBodegas = null;

            if (dsTemp != null)
            {
                DataTable oDtTemp = dsTemp.Tables[0];
                if (oDtTemp != null)
                {
                    listaBodegas = new BinWarehouse[oDtTemp.Rows.Count];
                    for (int i = 0; i < oDtTemp.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        DataRow orow = oDtTemp.Rows[i];
                        listaBodegas[i] = new BinWarehouse(orow["WarehouseId"].ToString(), orow["BinId"].ToString(), orow["BinDscr"].ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            return listaBodegas;
        }

        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<BinWarehouse> Get()
        {
            return MostrarLista();
            // return listaClientes;
        }


        // GET api/<controller>/44444444K
        public BinWarehouse[] Get(String dni)
        { 
                return    MostrarLista().Where(x => x.WarehouseId.Trim() == dni).ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: take a look at attribute routing

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to include route configuration that support the desired URIs. Take into account that they will be evaluated in the order they're registered, and the first matching route will be used. So you must include first the more specific ones, and then the most general ones. Apart from matching the route structure you define the parameters, and choose the controller and the action.

Your routes could look like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "BinWarehouse",
    routeTemplate: "api/warehouse/{warehouseId}/Binwarehouse/{binId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "BinWarehouse", action = "MostrarLista" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "BinWarehouse",
    routeTemplate: "api/warehouse/{warehouseId}/Binwarehouse",
    defaults: new { controller = "Warehouse", action = "MostrarLista" }
);
```

Your actions must receive the parameters captured by the route (route parameters), i.e.

```
public BinWarehouse[] MostrarLista(int warehouseId, int binId)

public Warehouse[] MostrarLista(int warehouseId)
```

*However, be warned that you should learn much more about routing and Web API in general to do things in the right way. This is basic stuff that you should now before start working with this technology. Please, at least read quickly this docs: [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api)*

If you read the docs, specially those related to routing, you'll see that you can alternatively use attribute routing, and how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Just create specific Get methods for each specification of data you want returned, that way you can pass arguments to the REST services based on data needed.

```
//Current Get() Methods

//Access url would like /BinWarehouse?warehouseNum=001&binNum=020
public IEnumerable<BinWarehouse> Get(string warehouseNum, string binNum){
  //Grab specific data and return it
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to make work the URIs he wants to use, not how to write a different URI that works.